# Unable to send list of object containing file to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to send a list of objects from my view to controller. Every object has a file along with some other properties. 
Here is the model:

```
public class FilesUploadModel
    {
        public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
        public string fileTaskId { get; set; }
        public bool upload { get; set; }
        public bool read { get; set; }
        public bool import { get; set; }
        public bool isReupload { get; set; }
        public int fileReadId { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FileSave(List<FilesUploadModel> models)
        {}
```

And this is how I am trying to send the list to controller:

```
var filesUploadModel = [];
function someFn(){
   var uploadModel = {
                        file = someInput.files[0]
                        fileTaskId: "2563",
                        upload: true,
                        read: true,
                        import: true,
                        isReupload: false,
                        fileReadId: 0
                    }
                    filesUploadModel.push(uploadModel);
}
function UploadFiles(){
        var formData = new FormData();

          filesUploadModel.forEach(function (model) {  //filesUploadModel is the list 
            formData.append('models', model);
          });

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Company/FileSave",
            type: 'POST',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            complete: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
```

But I am unable to receive data in the controller. Couldn't figure out the issue here.

Comment: Do you get an error? what do you get when you debug the server side?

Comment: @Sagivb.g I just get an empty list on the server side.

Comment: Other values are ok?

Comment: I am just sending list of FilesUploadModel objects and it is empty on the server side. So, there won't be any other values.

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending a list of files but yet instead an object with a list of files, change your Action to receive an object with a property of list of files

```
public ActionResult FileSave(FileSaveRequest request)
{

}


public class FileSaveRequest{

 public List<FilesUploadModel> Models { get;set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue. As we're trying to pass a collection of objects, we need to add each one of them with an index:

```
    filesUploadModel.forEach(function (model, i) {
        formData.append('models[' + i + '].file', model.file);
        formData.append('models[' + i + '].fileTaskId', model.fileTaskId);
        formData.append('models[' + i + '].upload', model.upload);
        formData.append('models[' + i + '].read', model.read);
        formData.append('models[' + i + '].import', model.import);
        formData.append('models[' + i + '].isReupload', model.isReupload);
        formData.append('models[' + i + '].fileReadId', model.fileReadId);
    });
```